# Redrawing grid on event

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

In my Angular application have a grid that is rendered on page load.  I would like to redraw/rerender that same grid when I click on a row.  I am doing this because clicking on a row fires another GET request for remote data to populate a div inside the grid's rows.  Of course, I need to change the row height for the grid once I get the response to show all of the data from the response, and this is why I need to redraw the grid.

In my html:

```
<ng-template #displayListData>

        <ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 100%" class="ag-material grid-Holdings"
            [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
            [rowData]="rowData"
            [getRowHeight]="getRowHeight"
            headerHeight="46"
            (gridReady)="prepareGrid()"
            [isFullWidthCell]="isFullWidthCell"
            [doesDataFlower]="doesDataFlower"
            [fullWidthCellRendererFramework]="getFullWidthCellRenderer()"
            (rowClicked)="redrawGrid($event)">
        </ag-grid-angular>

</ng-template>
```

In my component I have a method redrawGrid() that is firing when I click on a row.  In this method I tried calling setRowHeight() and resetRowHeight() but it did not work...the method fires but the grid is not redrawn according to the new height passed:

```
redrawGrid(params: any): void {

    //TRIED BOTH DID NOT WORK
    params.node.setRowHeight(this.newRowHight);
    // this.gridOptions.api.resetRowHeights();
}
```

Here is the getRowHeight() method in the same component:

```
getRowHeight(params) {
        let isDetailRow = params.node.level === 1;
        let rowHeight: number = this.newRowHeight;
        // my new rowHeight or 48px
        return isDetailRow ? rowHeight : 48;
}
```

I am new with ag-Grid, I wonder if I am over complicating the solution...

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation the solution was to call ag-Grid's setRowHeight on the childFlower of the node, like so:

```
redrawGrid(params: any): void {
        params.node.childFlower.setRowHeight(this.globalRowCount * 34);

        this.gridOptions.api.onRowHeightChanged();
}
```

But!  But...the hight will not change and the grid will not redraw unless you call `onRowHeightChanged()`

See "Changing Row Height" at https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-height/#gsc.tab=0